# If you draw 4 balls at random without replacement, what's the probability that exactly 2 of them are red?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

A box contains 7 red balls, 5 blue balls, & 3 green balls. If you draw 4 balls at random without replacement, what's the probability that exactly 2 of them are red?

**My attempt -**

I calculated the probabilities of each of the following cases -

Picking in the following sequence -

1. Red, Red, Not Red, Not Red
2. Not Red, Not Red, Red, Red
3. Red, Not Red, Not Red, Red
4. Red, Not Red, Red, Not Red

For the first sequence - 7/15 x 6/14 x 8/13 x 7/12

For the second sequence - 8/15 x 7/14 x 7/13 x 6/12

For the third sequence - 7/15 x 8/14 x 7/13 x 6/12

For the forth sequence - 7/15 x 8/14 x 6/13 x 7/12

To find the total probability, I summed the probabilities of all four sequences.

Final answer I got was 29/85, but it seems incorrect. Any inputs or guidance would be much appreciated

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: As a further criticism, questions very similar to this one have been beaten to death on MathSE.  I suggest that you search MathSE postings for such keywords as "urn" and/or "ball" and/or "red".

Comment: Have you been taught formulas for drawing without replacement ? If not, whar have you been taught so far ? And  if you have tried *anything*, edit it in. On this forum, you are expected to first show whatever efforts you have made.

Comment: A relevant keyword to search in your book or the internet would be "*Hypergeometric Distribution*" (*or "multivariate hypergeometric distribution if you insist", but it is far easier to simply say there are 7 red balls and 8 "not-red" balls*).  That being said, although this is the formal name given to the distribution in literature, I had not personally learned its name until after my first course or two on the subject.  Developing the distribution can be done on your own following from first principles.

Comment: You missed two of the possible sequences of observed ball colors (red vs. not red). And you did not use combinatorics, which would have made the entire calculation much easier.

Comment: By the way, the sum of your four probabilities is $56/195$, so you also made at least one arithmetic error somewhere.

Comment: My approach is to first estimate the magnitude. We can obtain 0,1,2,3 or 4 Red-balls, so 5 different results ; and 2 is the most frequent result (because ...) ; so the probability should be something like 30%  (more than 20% and less than 50%) ; then I start serious computation, and I check if the result matches with predictions. If it doesn't match, I need to double-check where is my error. Final result is 43%, ok, no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are in fact *six* orders of red vs notred possible here.  Letting $X$ be "notred" you only mentioned $RRXX,~XXRR,~RXXR$ and $RXRX$.  You missed the remaining two $XRRX$ and $XRXR$.

All six of these do result in the same calculation of $\dfrac{7\times 6\times 8\times 7}{15\times 14\times 13\times 12}$ with some possible reordering of terms in the numerator... but thanks to commutativity of multiplication we can recognize that the final result of each should be the same.  Yes, they could have started as separate fractions like $\dfrac{7}{15}\times \dfrac{6}{14}\times \dfrac{8}{13}\times \dfrac{7}{12}$ but it can benefit us to think of it all as a combined fraction.  Again, basic properties of arithmetic allow us this simplification.

This approach should have gotten us to the final answer of $6\times \dfrac{7\times 6\times 8\times 7}{15\times 14\times 13\times 12} = \dfrac{28}{65}$ which is indeed correct.

I do not know how you arrived at $\dfrac{29}{85}$ since even with having only added four copies rather than six it should have gotten you to $\frac{56}{195}$ so there must have been some arithmetic errors involved in your attempt.

---

This all being said... you should *not* be dealing with so much tedious arithmetic.  The point of a course in combinatorics is to learn how to count things *without* brute force listing of outcomes and *without* using your fingers to assist counting.  Make simplifications.  Use symmetry to help.  Take more efficient approaches.

Here, we make the simplification that we draw every ball **simultaneously**, which will not affect the overall probability.  We also make the simplification that each ball is uniquely labeled to allow us more freedom in describing our sample space.

There are $\binom{15}{4}$ ways to simultaneously draw four balls if order is irrelevant and each ball is uniquely labeled.  Of these, to draw exactly two red balls and two other balls can be done by picking the two red balls to use and picking the two non-red balls to use in $\binom{7}{2}\binom{8}{2}$ ways.

The final probability then is simply:

$$\dfrac{\binom{7}{2}\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{15}{4}}=\dfrac{588}{1365}=\dfrac{28}{65}$$

In general, with $N$ total balls where $K$ of which are red and the remaining $N-K$ are not red, and when taking $n$ balls at a time without replacement, the probability that exactly $k$ of the selected balls are red will be described by the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution) as occurring with probability:

$$\dfrac{\binom{K}{k}\binom{N-K}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$$

For what it is worth, the final answer is in many cases best left unsimplified as $\dfrac{\binom{7}{2}\binom{8}{2}}{\binom{15}{4}}$ unless explicitly requested to simplify and evaluate everything in the expression.  By seeing the answer in this form, it allows the teacher/grader the ability to see your reasoning where the answer came from and more quickly judge its correctness.

Answer (score 0):

The number of ways $2$ red balls can be arranged among $4$ is equal to $^4C_2 = 6$

The number of ways each one of the 6 above arrangments can be such that it has exactly $2$ red balls = $7 \times 6 \times 8 \times 7 = 2352$

The total number of ways we can have exactly 2 red balls = $6 \times 2352$

The total number of ways 4 balls can be selected = $^{15}P_4 = 32760$

The probability of getting exactly $2$ red balls = $\frac{14112}{32760}$